# Implementing publish() function using old Pub/Sub API client python library on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, mqtt, iot, google-cloud-pubsub

I have written a code for implementing pub/sub on Google Cloud Platform using old API client libraries in python. I need to publish a message from my pubsub server to a MQTT client. The code which I have written -

```
PRIVATE_KEY_JSON = 'My First Project-ac2738b37b2b.json'
API_SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    PRIVATE_KEY_JSON, scopes=API_SCOPES)
pubsub = discovery.build('pubsub', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
PROJECT_NAME = 'sonorous-treat-167211'
PROJECT = 'projects/{0}'.format(PROJECT_NAME)

topics = pubsub.projects().topics().list(project=PROJECT)
topic_name = "to-gateway"
sub_name = "my_test2"
response = pubsub.projects().topics().publish(topic='{0}/topics/{1}'.format(PROJECT, topic_name), body={ "messages" :[{  "attributes" : {"key":"topic","value" : "gateway-command/foo4",}, "data" : "HIII",},], }).execute()
#response = pubsub.projects().subscriptions().create(name ='{0}/subscriptions/{1}'.format(PROJECT, sub_name),body = { "ackDeadlineSeconds": 42, "topic" : '{0}/topics/{1}'.format(PROJECT, topic_name) , "name" : '{0}/subscriptions/{1}'.format(PROJECT, sub_name), }).execute()
##response = pubsub.projects().topics().create(name ='{0}/topics/{1}'.format(PROJECT, topic_name),body = {}).execute()
string = response
@app.route('/')
def form():
    #string1 = list_topics()
    #publish_message("projects/sonorous-treat-167211/topics/to-gateway", "HII")
    return render_template('submitted_form.html',mydict = string)
```

Currently I am not getting any error in my code. But After publishing the message, I am not receiving the message on the client side. I am not getting where the issue is. May be the pub/sub api is not able to interact with the IOT Adapter. I have also used the new google cloud pub/sub libraries(currently in alpha version) but getting the same issue.

Here is the docs of publish() -

```
publish(topic=None, body=*, x__xgafv=None)
Adds one or more messages to the topic. Returns `NOT_FOUND` if the topic
does not exist. The message payload must not be empty; it must contain
 either a non-empty data field, or at least one attribute.

Args:
  topic: string, The messages in the request will be published on this topic.
Format is `projects/{project}/topics/{topic}`. (required)
  body: object, The request body. (required)
    The object takes the form of:

{ # Request for the Publish method.
    "messages": [ # The messages to publish.
      { # A message data and its attributes. The message payload must not be empty;
          # it must contain either a non-empty data field, or at least one attribute.
        "attributes": { # Optional attributes for this message.
          "a_key": "A String",
        },
        "data": "A String", # The message payload.
        "publishTime": "A String", # The time at which the message was published, populated by the server when
            # it receives the `Publish` call. It must not be populated by the
            # publisher in a `Publish` call.
        "messageId": "A String", # ID of this message, assigned by the server when the message is published.
            # Guaranteed to be unique within the topic. This value may be read by a
            # subscriber that receives a `PubsubMessage` via a `Pull` call or a push
            # delivery. It must not be populated by the publisher in a `Publish` call.
      },
    ],
  }
```

Comment: In the code as you have presented it, you are calling `publish` and then calling `create` on a subscription, but that line is commented out. Are you always publishing the message before creating the subscription?

Comment: I suppose the subscription will be created from the client side. So I have used a MQTT client and created subscription for the topic overthere. I just need to publish using the Pub/Sub